# Extract a value from an array of objects

Tags: ruby

I have an array as follows:

```
 [{:type=>"adSource", :value=>"27"}, {:type=>"adSource", :value=>"28"}]
```

I'd like to get `[27,28]`, converted to int. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 ary = [{:type=>"adSource", :value=>"27"}, {:type=>"adSource", :value=>"28"}]
 ary.map{ |h| h[:value].to_i }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
data.map { |v| v[:value] }.map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Extracting the strings into an array then converting the strings to integers in a separate step is wasteful. Better to convert the strings to integers as they being extracted, as @Bartosz has done.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{:type=>"adSource", :value=>"27"}, {:type=>"adSource", :value=>"28"}]
```

And then you can get your required result by:

```
arr.map{|x| x[:value].to_i}
```

Comment: Sorry for the repetition, but when I typed the answer, there were zero answers for this post. Again, I am sorry for any inconvenience.